# How does Mathematica numerically integrate to infinity?

Tags: numerical-integration, implementation-details

Suppose you have a function that can only be evaluated numerically. I.e., you call $f[x]$ with a particular value of $x$ and get a value after a brief amount of time, but there is no good way of writing the $f$ in terms of other functions.

Yet if the function call doesn't take too long (and the integral exists), Mathematica usually produces sensible output to `NIntegrate[f[x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]` in a fairly short amount of time.

How does this algorithm work? In theory there is no hope of finding this integral numerically, since the function might be nonzero only in a small patch somewhere buried between $-\infty$ and $\infty$, e.g., $f[x]=1, \text{for}\,x\in[10^{235},10^{235}+1]$ and $f=0$ otherwise, 
or $f[x]=1,\,\text{for}\,x\in[1.235643,1.235644]$ and $f=0$ otherwis.

Does Mathematica limit itself to double precision numbers (still vast!). How does it know which scale to probe at? Does anyone know what sort of algorithm is being used? Does `NIntegrate` assume some amount of smoothness?

Comment: It uses a bunch of special methods (e.g. double exponential quadrature) for infinite integrals.

Comment: Looking at the way Gauss quadrature works by evaluating the function at the zeros of an orthogonal polynomial over the integration domain and then looking at the zeros of the Laguerre polynomials (which cover (0,oo)) was very educational for me to kind of 'get' how integration on infinite support is possible. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Other_forms). And yes, it's not possible to exclude wrong result from pathological functions because you are limited to a finite number of samples.

Comment: [This](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateOverview.html) part of the documentation also has in depth info how the different numerical integration strategies inside Mathematica work.